# Using pythons DOTALL flag to retrive data from an unknown number of lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to retrieve a paragraph with newlines, so I'm using pythons DOTALL flag with the compilation S flag (DOTALL, S = "Make . match any character, including newlines") but I still can't get it to work.

In the example below I'm trying to obtain the data from the first `[**]` to the last `[**]`

> `[**]` blah etc `[**]`
>
> etc
>
> etc (etc lines repeat and unknown number of times)
>
> `[**]` blah etc2......

N.B. there are no blank newlines above, apart from the one the proceeds the next block i.e. blah etc2 (just couldn’t get it to format correctly)

My attempt below didn't retrieve anything:

`re.compile(r'\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\]', re.DOTALL|re.S)`

However, up until the last star i.e.

`(r'\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\].*`

it will retrieve just the first line (as expected) but adding on the `\[\*{2}\]` doesn't return anything.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

#

It appears my error was when I was reading the file in I was using:

`with open ("c:/location", r) as txt:
    for i in txt:`

where I should have used:

`with open ("c:/location", r) as txt:
    lines=txt.read()`

Thank-you for all your responses, and @tripleee you set me on the correct path to understand my error was not in the regex but with reading the file in, thank you.

Comment: -1 Works for me: http://pastebin.com/bYfebJk1

Comment: Not really sure what your issue is, but it might be better to match each newline with \n rather than using DOTALL to be more specific about what you're matching.

Answer (score 0):

Only considering your regex (without being clear what you want to do - sorry) 
This regex:

```
\[\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\]
```

Will match anything from the first `[**]` up tp the last `[**]` it finds

This regex:

```
\[\*{2}\].*?\[\*{2}\]
```

Will match anything in between `[**]` and `[**]`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you beginned your first attempt by `\*{2}\].*`. I used this :

```
re.compile(r'\[\*{2}\](.*)\[\*{2}\]', re.DOTALL)
```

and it correctly matches everything between 2 `[**]`, even multiline.

I added the parentheses to capture in `group(1)` the inner, ie the string without the  `[**]`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I've been trying to get my head around it.  Basically I began with `\*{2}\].*` as I wanted to collect all the data in each "blah etc" group (including said title).  Then I wanted to pass that into another function which I could run other regex searches on.  Nevertheless, thank you.